# How to control and optimize optuna

Tags: finetuning, catboost

i'm here with a pretty open question.

I'm using Optuna to fine tune a Catboost Regressor and i've found, trying a set of parameters by hand, that the "best params" it outputs are not the best ones.

Here's my question: are there methods to control and "optimize" the performance of optuna?

That's the objective function i'm using:

```
def objective(trial, X, y, save_folder, cat_features):
    params = {
        'iterations': trial.suggest_int('iterations', 1000, 40000, 5000),
        'learning_rate': trial.suggest_float('learning_rate', 0.001, 0.1, log=True),
        'depth': trial.suggest_int('depth', 4, 10),
        'l2_leaf_reg': trial.suggest_float('l2_leaf_reg', 1e-3, 10.0, log=True),
        'min_child_samples': trial.suggest_int('min_child_samples', 1, 10),
        'grow_policy': 'Depthwise',
        'use_best_model': True,  
        'eval_metric': 'RMSE',
        'od_type': 'iter',
        'od_wait': 50,
        'random_state': 42,
        'has_time': True
    }
```